# For loop in Play Framework Java

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, twirl, play-templates

In Play Framework template, I'm trying to iterate between to numbers using for loop.

When I use:

```
@for(i <- 2010 to 2015)
```

it works fine. Also, for

```
@for(i <- 2010 to Constants.CURRENT_YEAR)
```

it works correctly (gets predefined constant for CURRENT_YEAR from imported class Constants). However, when I try to exchange both numbers with variables

```
@for(i <- Constants.FIRST_YEAR to Constants.CURRENT_YEAR)
```

I get an error "value to is not a member of Integer".

Could somebody please tell me what am I doing wrong? I tried putting variables in {} but with no success, and I couldn't find an example with this particular situation.

Comment: what is `Constants`? Would you share it please?

Comment: Constants is a public class with public static Strings:

public static Integer FIRST_YEAR = 2010;
public static Integer CURRENT_YEAR = 2015;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I create the Constants class :

```
public class Constants {
   public static final int MIN = 1;
   public static final int MAX = 10;
}
```

And i add the next code in *.scala.html file.

```
 @for(i <- Constants.MIN to Constants.MAX){
     i
 }
```

And its good !

Comment: Thank you, this solution works for me too! For some reason, template didn't work when constant type was Integer, but with int it works fine.